# Footable expand only 1 row at a time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, footable

Im using Footable for my data. [here's an official example](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/basic/row-toggle.html).
With beakpoints i can hide some data and expand it when necessary...
But i want to expand one row at a time and close the other expanded rows.

With Footable i figured out i can access the event of expanding a row like:

```
 $("#footableID").on("expand.ft.row", function (e, ft, row) {
    var rows=$('#footableID tbody').children("tr");
    // hide expanded data
});
```

but i cant find a way to hide the expanded rows...
I tried removing the data-expanded="true" attribute to the rows,but that dosnt seems to work...
also, im not sure if children is the best way to access the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so "find" is a better way to acces row childs, and when you got a expanded row, you have to trigger a click to close it.
...if i understand correctly expand.ft.row occurres before it is actually expanded

```
$("#tabla").on("expand.ft.row", function (e, ft, row) {
    $('#tabla tbody').find('tr').each(function(){
        if (this.getAttribute("data-expanded")){
            this.click(); 
        }
    })
});
```